# Collection field with custom subquery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I need to fill collection property with custom join through third table. I try something like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@ElementCollection
@Formula(value = "SELECT p.* " +
        "FROM typed_permission tp " +
        "JOIN permission p ON tp.permission = p.id " +
        "WHERE tp.principal_uuid = 'ORG_ROLE:' || code")
private Set<Permission> permissions;
```

Also I want to do this with @JoinTable, but there is no place to @Formula.

How to write this property correctly?